# Lightning aura :attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Issue: I have displaying a set of questions and answers which can be edited from UI. When user selects cancel all answer should revert back to same as stored in database for which i am using storeResult attribute and sqQue to iterate in UI. But i see in handleCancel function both the attributes are storing the same modified value from UI. Any reason for this behaviour? also, how can i revert back the attribute to it's initial state?

below is my component:

```
<aura:component controller="abc">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="storeResult" type="List" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="sqQue" type="List" default=""/>

    <aura:if  isTrue="{!not(empty(v.sqQue))}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.sqQue}" var="section">
            <form class="slds-form--inline">
                <div class="slds-form-element"><br/>
            <lightning:input  name="input4"  value="{!section.sQUniueinpvalue}" label="{!section.sQUniueLabel}" />
        <br/>
                </div></form>
                </aura:iteration>
        <div>
            <lightning:button variant="base" label="Save" title="Save" onclick="{! c.handleSave }"/>
            <lightning:button variant="base" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{! c.handleCancel }"/>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

JS file:

```
({
    doInit:function(comp,event,helper){
    helper.Doinitial(comp,event);    
    },

    handleSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.handleSave(component, event,helper);

    },

    handleCancel: function(comp,event,helper){
        helper.handleCancel(comp,event,helper);
    }
})
```

and Helper file:

```
({
    Doinitial:function(component,event){
        var  recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log('recordId',recordId);
        var action=component.get("c.getSecurityQues");
        action.setParams({
            "caseId" : recordId
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.storeResult",result);
                component.set("v.sqQue",result);
            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
            }            
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },


    handleSave: function(component,event,helper){
         var action=component.get("c.saveSecurityQues");
        action.setParams({
            "secQuesList" : component.get("v.sqQue")
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
             if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
console.log("success");

            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
            }
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    handleCancel:function(comp,event,helper){
        let answers =  comp.get("v.storeResult");
          comp.set("v.sqQue",answers);
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the `{}` tool to format your code. Thanks! I've fixed it here.

Comment: @DavidReed: Hi David: Can you please help me in deleting my account? As i see none of my questions are being answered so i prefer to opt out of this community

Comment: I am sorry that this community has not been successful in engaging you. If your mind is made up, you may [initiate your account deletion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).